# Is it possible to implement java interface AudioTrack.OnCodecFormatChangedListener from cpp

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, swig

We have a multimedia player SDK where all the source files are in CPP. We have a requirement that we need to register a listener with the android audioTrack by calling the following method
`addOnCodecFormatChangedListener`.

Using the JNI interface I can easily call the above method from CPP.

This method takes two objects as arguments:

1. Executor object
2. Listener object

Please refer the following for more information.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack#addOnCodecFormatChangedListener(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.media.AudioTrack.OnCodecFormatChangedListener)

To create an object of the listener class, I need to implement the AudioTrack's `onCodecFormatChangedListener`.

Following is an example of how we implement the `onCodecFormatChangedListener` in Java:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.OnCodecFormatChangedListener

```
public class AudioTrackListener implements AudioTrack.OnCodecFormatChangedListener{

    @Override
    public void onCodecFormatChanged (AudioTrack audioTrack, 
                AudioMetadataReadMap info) {
        // Handle onCodecFormatChanged event
    }
}
```

As our player doesn't have the `.java` files, I should do everything in cpp. Is it possible to somehow implement the Java interface in C++, create an object, and pass it to the AudioTrack? When audioTrack invokes, even the implemented method from the C++ should get called.

**In summary:**
How can I implement the Java interface from the CPP